# ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I wanted to deploy my Smart Contract on testnet but I got an error,
below is the code

```py
from brownie import accounts, config,SimpleStorage


def deploy_simple_storage():
    account=accounts.load("freecodecamp-account")
    # print(account)
    simple_storage=SimpleStorage.deploy({"from":account})
    stored_value=simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)
    transaction=simple_storage.store(15,{"from":account})
    transaction.wait(1)
    updated_storage_value=simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(updated_storage_value)

def get_account():
 if network.show_active=="development":
    return accounts[0]
 else:
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

and I got the following error message:

```
brownie run scripts/deployyy.py --network goerli
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 45, in main     
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 40, in connect
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 54, in connect
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", line 185, in _expand_environment_vars
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
```

I used the API key from infura for Project id.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not yet have one, go sign up for an account with [infura](https://infura.io)

create a new ETH project in infura

run this command, with your project key of course, in the terminal where you have your brownie script being run

note: sometimes the terminal "forgets" and you have to re run this command

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=your_infura_key
```

finally run your deploy command once again

Comment: sorry but its not working,getting the same error

Comment: @HarshSaw no need to apologize (: could you please put the steps you took in your post above and let me know once you have?